# Proving two equivalent statement that come from Otto Holder's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

$a \in \ell_q$ and $x \in \ell_p$. We also have $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

I want to show that
$$
 \cfrac{|a_ix_i|}{||x||_p ||a||_q}
\leq
 \cfrac{1}{p}\left(\cfrac{|x_i|}{||x||_p} \right)
+\cfrac{1}{q}\left(\cfrac{|a_i|}{||a||_q} \right) \\
\implies
\cfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_ix_i|}{||x||_p||a||_q} \leq 1
$$

I started with

$$
\cfrac{\sum |a_ix_i|}{||x||_p ||a||_q}
\leq
 \cfrac{1}{p}\left(\cfrac{\sum |x_i|}{||x||_p} \right)
+\cfrac{1}{q}\left(\cfrac{\sum |a_i|}{||a||_q} \right)
$$

and then I expanded the summations and wrote out the definition for the $p$-norm and $q$-norm but I don't see how to make the terms disappear. I know that the norms must converge to be a valid element of the space but this fact didn't help me reduce the RHS to 1. I know that somehow the right hand side should add to one but I'm stuggling to see it.

---

The comments make me think that there's a mistake in the homework. Here's an image of the problem.

[image]

Comment: The first is Young’s inequality, but you forgot the exponents p and q on the right side.

Comment: @MartinR does the assignment have a mistkake? Should there be exponents over the part in parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake. Just check what you have to substitute for $\alpha, \beta, \lambda$ to get the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
Use [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products)
for each summand.

This will look similar to your assumed inequality (maybe you meant to add the exponents so that it becomes Young's inequality).

*edit*: To address the edit of the question: Yes, there does seem to be a mistake. In the second part the exponents $p$ and $q$ are missing over the parts in the parentheses.

Comment: does the assignment have a mistake? Should there be exponents over the part in parenthesis?

Comment: @financial_physician: Yes. I edited my answer.